# App crashes when downloaded from Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, stack-trace

I've just built and deployed an app to Google Play.  It worked well when I was running it through Android Studio but now it crashes when I download it from Google Play.  Because this is my first time, I don't even know how to view the crash report/stacktrace of the app that was downloaded from Google Play.  I appreciate any and all help.

**UPDATE**

So I got the stacktrace for the APK.  It tells me that my `TopImageFragment.java` class cannot create my `MemeViewModel.java` class.  I have no clue why its giving this error.  Everything works fine as it is.  It seems that proguard is indeed phasing out an important class:

```
2019-04-18 00:46:32.062 8099-8099/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ozbek.onur.memegenerator, PID: 8099
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ozbek.onur.memegenerator/com.ozbek.onur.memegenerator.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.ozbek.onur.memegenerator.MemeViewModel
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2853)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2928)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1609)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6703)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:769)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.ozbek.onur.memegenerator.MemeViewModel
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:155)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:210)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:134)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:102)
        at com.ozbek.onur.memegenerator.TopImageFragment.onActivityCreated(TopImageFragment.java:89)
```

Comment: I suggest that you use the Report button when you get your crash in your device, and then look for the logs in Google Play console. With this you could edit your question to add more information. I the current state, there's not much more we can do to help you.

Comment: Idk what and where the google play console is

Comment: The Google Play web site where you deployed your app. A good alternative to what I suggested is what Mayank-Pandit suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you have any java files that don't have an access modifier.  In my experience, just declaring a class without a public or private modifier, causes this problem.

Comment: It turns out I've declared my `ViewModel` without an access modifier.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5):

This kind of problem usually happens because your app deployed to Google Play was a release build and proguard minified your app and removed a class it shouldn't have. When you build in Android Studio it is a debug build that does not get minified. That's why you see the crash only from Google Play.

Before uploading to Google Play, test out your release APK file on a device and watch logcat for the error. That should tell you what class got removed by mistake and you can correct that by specifying custom proguard rules and trying again until the app stops crashing. Then when you upload to Google Play, you should be good.

You can also enable proguard in a debug build as well by changing your build.gradle file. Then when you run through Android Studio, you should see the same error as you see through Google Play.

One other alternative, you can disable proguard/minification in your release build. However this is not recommended because your app will be larger than it needs to be.

Comment: I have a abb file.  Not apk.

Comment: And when I run my downloaded-app on my phone, I can't see it's stack trace on Android studio.

Comment: Try building an APK instead of AAB just as a test to see if you can get a stack trace. In Android Studio change the logcat tab to "No filter" and then clear it right before you launch your app. You should see the stack trace fly by. Scroll back to analyze it.

Comment: I've just posted the stacktrace.  It seems that proguard is phasing out an important class.

Comment: It may not be the class that is being removed, it may be the constructor for that class.  Try putting the @Keep annotation on both your MemeViewModel class and the constructor to see if that helps. And, make sure your view model has a no-arg public constructor.

Answer (score 1):

My app suffered the same problem and it was a ProGuard kill.
Because ProGuard renames all classes unless otherwise instructed.
So, in your case, you have to add

> @Keep

annotation before your class name **MemeViewModel**.

example,

```
@Keep
class MemeViewModel{
//
//
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my suggestion, keep your phone connected to your your PC/Laptop while you download and attempt to open it. Use Logcat on android studio, it mostly has all answers or at least errors that lead to the answers. try putting error logs here so we can have a proper look at it.

1) Try the same version of your application that you deployed on Google play store by pushing it through the android studio and see if the problem continues!

2) If same thing happens then put breakpoint on the entry point (onCreate method in most cases in MainActivity class) of your application and Go to Run->Debug "YourProject" option and do step by step debug for each command being executed and see which one is causing problem.